# Django - Postgresql: transaction and concurrency

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, concurrency, transactions

There is a lot of topics on Django concurrency, but after checking a lot of those, I don't feel I have found my answer when it comes to transactions.

Django version 1.3.1. Postgresql version 8.4.7.

A very simple version of my models could look like this:

```
def Member(Model):
  money = PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
  user = OneToOneField(User, related_name='member', primary_key=True)

def Bet(Model):
  total_money = PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

I also have a table Money which is a relation between Member and Bet. It's not directly linked to my problem but it helps me monitor it, because it can't be impacted by any concurrency issues. i.e I just have to count my table Money to test if the fields money of Member and total_money of Bet are correct.

I can't rely only on the table Money though, and I need my fields to be correct, because I filter a lot using them.

My first try for the bet function was something like this (just with a lot more modifications to a lot more tables).

```
def bid(user_pk, bet_pk, value):
  #create Money object
  member = User.objects.get(user_pk).member
  member.money = F('money') - value
  member.save()
  bet = Bet.objects.get(bet_pk)
  bet.total_money = F('total_money') + value
  bet.save()
```

This version was working just fine until I get my first crash during one transaction.
I had also to copy paste all the tests from my clean() functions in bid(), because I'm not really able to use clean() or full_clean() in this case (especially if bet raises, after member is saved).

So I decided to give a try to django transaction.

```
@transaction.commit_manually
def bid(user_pk, bet_pk, value):
  try:
    #create money object
    member = User.objects.get(user_pk).member
    member.money -= value
    member.clean()
    member.save()
    bet = Bet.objects.get(bet_pk)
    bet.total_money += value
    bet.clean()
    bet.save()
  except:
    transaction.rollback()
    raise
  else:
    transaction.commit()
```

But without the possibility to use F() object inside of manual transaction (which makes sense). I ended up with a lot of concurrency issues.

I see only two solutions:

- Only create Money objects during the bid()/transaction, then have an asynchronous worker (Celery ?) that updates the related fields in Member and Bet.
- Create a list of bid()/transaction (Redis ?), and make all transactions that modify money related fields synchronous.

Am I missing an obvious and easier solution ?
If not, what solution would you recommend using which technology ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

would this work?

`@transaction.commit_on_success
def bid(user_pk, bet_pk, value):
    Member.objects.filter(user__pk=user_pk).update(money=F('money') - value)
    Bet.objects.filter(pk=bet_pk).update(total_money=F('total_money') + value)`

Comment: At least it doesn't raise, which is already a nice improvement from my version with an use of transaction + F object. Thanks a lot. It's a bit late for me (I have a lot of modifications to make to try it), but I'll try that definitively tomorrow.

Comment: Ok all my tests are green with that solution, I'll push that on prod soon and check if I don't detect any concurrency issues anymore. The only drawbacks I see are:

- I can't use clean functions because obviously the value aren't updated.

- Pre save and post save functions don't work with update (and I wonder if update is really supposed to be used to modify one item)

- I had to drop the update of the money_max field I had in the Member table. I don't think you can write something like that with F: update(money_max=max(F('money'), F('money_max'))). I will just write my own sql query.

Comment: I found a way to do the max stuff:
    members = Member.objects.filter(user__id=member_pk)
    members.update(money=F('money') - value)
    members.filter(money_max__lt=F('money')).update(money_max=F('money'))